# why does the carousel slider wont load jpeg images?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, carousel

```
    <ul class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#slides" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#slides" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#slides" data-slide-to="2"></li>   

    </ul>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/kcochi.png" alt="First slide">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h1 class="display-2">CargoTrack</h1>
                <h3>Moving your products across all borders.</h3>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg">VIEW DEMO</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Get Started</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="img/background2.png">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="img/background3.png">
        </div>

    </div>
     <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#slides" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#slides" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>

</div>
```

This is my code and the slides work perfectly for every picture in png file . But jpeg images are not at all working. i tried to change filename of jpg into png , but still only some images work.
im a beginer at bootstrap

Comment: Please add the images also

Answer (score 0):

Works fine with jpgs...

if you want to add jpgs, you have to [convert](https://ezgif.com/png-to-jpg) pngs to jpgs.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="container">
      <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item active">
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/ny.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%;">
          </div>

          <div class="item">
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/chicago.jpg" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
          </div>

          <div class="item">
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/newyork.jpg" alt="New york" style="width:100%;">
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Left and right controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>

<!-- end snippet -->
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="container">
      <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item active">
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/ny.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%;">
          </div>

          <div class="item">
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/chicago.jpg" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
          </div>
        
          <div class="item">
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/newyork.jpg" alt="New york" style="width:100%;">
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Left and right controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```